# Can these data be grouped?

Tags: chi-squared-test

Whithin a certain population, I have selected three samples (in three different periods of time) and determined for each the frequency of individuals that present a specific characteristic. I want to determine if all these results can be grouped together or if there are differences between samples. Can I do it by performing a chi-square test for observed vs. expected frequencies and pooling the data if there are no significant differences?

If I do the sampling (three times also) in other populations, should I repeat the same procedure for each in order to determine if data from the same population can be pooled?

Answer (score 1):

**Question 1**
If your dataset is something like this

Sample 1           Yes=200             No=180

Sample 2           Yes=156             No=130

Sample 3           Yes=300             No=320

You can use chi-squared test.

**Question 2:**
I am not sure if I understood your second question. What do you mean with other populations?  Please, give a practical example

Comment: Population 1 Sample 1 Yes=200 No=180; 
Population 1 Sample 2 Yes=156 No=130; 
Population 1 Sample 3 Yes=300 No=320;  
Population 2 Sample 1 Yes=100 No=110; 
Population 2 Sample 2 Yes=116 No=100; 
Population 2 Sample 3 Yes=30 No=20. I want to know if I can pool together all data from the same population. Should I repeat the chi-square test for each population or there is a way to do the test for all at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest three samples in different periods will not be usefully susceptible to sophisticated analysis.

Whether they might be grouped should most obviously depend on their similarity… here, handicapped by there being only three samples.

When you want to determine "if all these results can be grouped together or if there are differences between samples", what differences have you in mind?

To the extent they were similar - ideally, identical - grouping samples over different times might work.

In the same time, how could three samples suffice for a chi-square test for observed v expected frequencies, or pooling of data?

You should repeat the same procedure for anything you hope to compare but whether that would allow data to be pooled would depend on the details.